# on a button click how to call a class and simultaneously insert values in database

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application in which there is a part where on a button click i am inserting values into the database and on the same button action a view controller is being called. This is my code for button action;

```
//this is my button action 
-(IBAction)Start:(id)sender{

    Gjourney = mTextJourney.text;
    Glocation = mTextLocation.text;
    Gmessage =mDescription.text;
    // Insert into the database function
    [self saveInDatabase];

    app=(JourneyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    //this is the class which i want to get called when i click on the button
    BreadcrumbViewController *st = [[BreadcrumbViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"BreadcrumbViewController" bundle:nil];

    [app.navController pushViewController:st animated:YES]; 
}
```

My problem is when the start button is clicked my data is saved in database but BreadcrumViewController class is not called. What may be the problem?

Comment: Did you set any breakpoint to see if the code is being called?

Comment: I'd start with checking if navController in app delegate is not nil.

Comment: Also, the question is a bit off. The class-call and the database-mutation is not happening simultaniously, but quickly after each other. If the database-mutation is working fine, but the calling of the class isn't, meaning removing all the database-mutation probably won't have any effect on the problem you are having. This is not something of a negative comment, I'm just hinting you should mind that, since people who might know the answer to your problem could get 'scared' of seeing the database-functionality and won't look here because they might think they can't solve it anyway :)

Comment: comment the app =  line and add import BreadcrumbViewController.h. See if that works.

Comment: ya i have added breakpoint in my code.it gets into each and every line of code but the problem is it does not show the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)Start:(id)sender{
Gjourney = mTextJourney.text;
Glocation = mTextLocation.text;
Gmessage =mDescription.text;
// Insert into the database function
[self saveInDatabase];

viewcontroller=[ViewController alloc ] initWithNibName:@"ViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController];
[viewController release];
}
```

This code should work fine.

Comment: infact i have added breakpoints in my code to check ,it gets into each and every line of my code but the problem is the class is not displayed

Comment: SOrry for delayed comment but I think you have problem in the saveInDatabse method can you reveal it.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self.navController pushViewController:st animated:YES];
```

Comment: but navController is created in appdelegate class so how can is directly access it in other class by calling self'

Comment: is your application navigation based or of other type

Comment: since it is declared in the delegate when you call self it referse to the base app class to. At least that's how i think it works please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: my application is windows based application

Answer (score 0):

Standard view passing is something like this i import the header, then

```
BreadcrumbViewController *detailViewController = [[BreadcrumbViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BreadcrumbViewController" bundle:nil];
        // ...
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
        [detailViewController release];
```

If that doesn't work check to see if your navigation controller is ok
, you might not have it setup in your delegate